# R dataframe: aggregate by group and convert to frequency count

Tags: r, dataframe, count, aggregate

I'm new to R and was wondering whether anyone could help me with a problem:

I have a dataframe like this:

| panelist_id | type | refer_sm | refer_se |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HP | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | HP | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | PB | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | PB | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | TN | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | HP | 1 | 0 |

I want to produce a dataframe that aggregates the number of visits to type per panelist, and the number of 'refers' to a type, at the panelist_id level, such as:

| panelist_id | No. visits to type: HP | No. visits to type PB | No. visits to type TN | No. refers from sm to HP | No. refers from sm to PB | No. refers from sm to TN | No. refers from se to HP | No. refers from se to PB | No. refers from se to TN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried using aggregate and summarise functions without much success. Any solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Create a column of 1s  (`n`), then use `pivot_wider` specifying the `names_from` as 'type' and `values_from` with 'n' and the 'refer' columns, specifying the `values_fn` as `sum` and the `values_fill` as 0 (to return 0 where there are no combinations - by default it returns `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(n = 1) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = c(n, refer_sm, refer_se),
           values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#  panelist_id  n_HP  n_PB  n_TN refer_sm_HP refer_sm_PB refer_sm_TN refer_se_HP refer_se_PB refer_se_TN
#        <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#1           1     2     1     0           1           0           0           1           1           0
#2           2     0     1     0           0           0           0           0           1           0
#3           3     1     0     1           1           0           1           0           0           0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(panelist_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), type = c("HP", 
"HP", "PB", "PB", "TN", "HP"), refer_sm = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), refer_se = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `reshape` + `aggregate`

```
reshape(
  aggregate(. ~ panelist_id + type, cbind(df, n = 1), sum),
  idvar = "panelist_id",
  timevar = "type",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

gives

```
  panelist_id refer_sm.HP refer_se.HP n.HP refer_sm.PB refer_se.PB n.PB
1           1           1           1    2           0           1    1
2           3           1           0    1          NA          NA   NA
4           2          NA          NA   NA           0           1    1
  refer_sm.TN refer_se.TN n.TN
1          NA          NA   NA
2           1           0    1
4          NA          NA   NA
```

---

Or, we can use `xtabs`

```
cbind(
  xtabs(~ panelist_id + type, df),
  xtabs(refer_sm ~ ., aggregate(refer_sm ~ panelist_id + type, df, sum)),
  xtabs(refer_se ~ ., aggregate(refer_se ~ panelist_id + type, df, sum))
)
```

gives

```
  HP PB TN HP PB TN HP PB TN
1  2  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
3  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```